# Why does Azure template error with resource not found?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to use an Azure deployment template to create an endpoint with a particular `deliveryPolicy`.  I run:

```
az deployment sub create --location UKSouth --template-file azuredeploy.json 
--parameters azuredeploy.parameters.json
```

which errors with:

```
"The Resource 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/GEN-UNIQUE' under resource group '<null>' 
was not found.
```

My deployment file looks like:

```
    ..."resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles",
    "apiVersion": "2020-09-01",
    "name": "[parameters('profileName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('CDNSku')]"
    },
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "endpoints",...
```

and my parameters file looks like:

```
    "profileName": {
    "value": "GEN-UNIQUE"
}
```

So how do I set the resource (and/or the resource group) correctly? (I only try to create the profile since I couldn't find an example of creating an endpoint without this step)

Answer (score 1):

This worked (or at least no error):

```
az deployment group create --resource-group myrg
```